# Ubuntu - Razer Polychromatic not detecting my Kraken 7.1 Chroma's

Tags: drivers, services

Long story short, I am trying to install the non native Razer Drivers for my headset so I can mess around more with my headset setting (like bass boost for example) I am using Ubuntu 16.04 LTS and would really love it if someone helped, thanks.

On the installation document on the git-hub page of Polychromatic it tells you the exact USB VID:PID's of which products are supported, so I typed in 'lsusb | grep '1532:'' into the command line like it says and it comes up with;

*Bus 004 Device 004: ID 1532:0504 Razer USA, Ltd*

Which is great because it says the product with this USB VID:PID (Kraken 7.1 Chroma's) are supported so I am not really sure why It is not getting recognized when I launch the Polychromatic Controller. There is no the daemon could be broken surely because Its a super fresh install.

Update: I just found the troubleshooting guide and went through it all but nothing changed, the only semi hopefully response I got from putting a certain command into the command was the command sudo gpasswd -a benjamin plugdev which gave me the message adding benjamin to group plugdev. Not sure if thats normal or it does it every time I enter that command.

Comment: After you ran the command to add your user to plugdev, did you reboot your system for changes to take effect?

Comment: Ah, no. I will do that now and update you on any change.

Comment: No luck, I am still getting the same error that I got last time.

Comment: This is a screen shot of the error I am getting:  http://i.imgur.com/VVpixuf.png

Comment: Polychromatic may not work with the headset.  Did you check in the sound settings under Output Devices if it shows up there?

Comment: It should work with Polychromatic because it is listed as one of the compatible devices with the VID:PID 1532:0504 and yes it is detected in my sound settings.

Comment: http://i.imgur.com/7YmATpJ.png, here is my sound settings. I am going to try and go to this page https://github.com/lah7/polychromatic/blob/master/README.md which lists all the dependencies I need and install them all manually just in case for some reason they did not properly install during installation. Do you know of any alternations of Polychromatics I could use in case this does not work?

Comment: Did you run `sudo apt install razer-kernel-modules-dkms`.  Also try installing `dkms` if it is not installed:  `sudo apt install dkms`.  Then after that, make sure the Razer kernel driver is installed correctly by running `sudo dpkg-reconfigure razer-kernel-modules-dkms`

Comment: Okay I will go through those steps instead.

Comment: I did all the commands mentioned in said order and all of them came back fine saying I did not need to install anything else, except for sudo dpkg-reconfigure razer-kernel-modules-dkms which seemed to go through its regular procedure so I dont think I have dont it before. I will restart and tell you if anythings changed.

Comment: Nope, no change. Same error as last time.

Comment: I wouldn't know anymore of what to tell you as to why the application is not detecting your headphones.  I have a razer keyboard and that is exactly what I did and it detected it in the application just fine.  Those are exactly the steps I have taken.  Sorry I can't be much more help than this.

Comment: Okay, now worries. One thing which has come up is people have been talking about that there Razer drivers are in the directory sys/bus I think but mine are not in there :/ There are only the HID drivers there.

Comment: If it helps, mine aren't in there either.  But, I since I don't have the headphones, only a keyboard, it might be different for me.  Good luck!  I really do hope you find an answer.  I am grasping at straws trying to help, but since I don't own the headphones I probably will not have a good answer.  I hate writing answers when I cannot duplicate the problem exactly.  +1

Comment: It all good :) I posted this but slightly different on the GitHub issues page so maybe I will get a fix there as they more 'specialize' in this area.